# Do screen transitions when the user clicks on a bitmap

Tags: blackberry

I am working on an eBook app where I need to transition the screens from left to right and right to left. I tried many samples that I've found, but I am not successful. How do I change the screen frequently when user clicks on the screen from left to right and right to left. What is the basic idea for transition of pages. I went through the Developer Support Forum thread ["page-flip effect"](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/page-flip-effect/m-p/716307/highlight/true#M138464) looking for a solution, but I can't see it.

The following code is not logical. In which position do I have to implement flip effect for flipping pages in the screen and how to implement it?

```
public class TransitionScreen extends FullScreen implements Runnable{

     private int angle = 0;
     Bitmap fromBmp,toBmp;

    public TransitionScreen(){

    }
    public TransitionScreen(AnimatableScreen from,AnimatableScreen to) {

           fromBmp = new Bitmap(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
           toBmp = new Bitmap(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
         Graphics fromGraphics =  Graphics.create(fromBmp);
         Graphics toGraphics =  Graphics.create(toBmp);

         Object eventLock = getApplication().getEventLock();

         synchronized(eventLock) {

              from.drawAnimationBitmap(fromGraphics);

              to.drawAnimationBitmap(toGraphics);
             // Interpolate myOffset to target

             // Set animating = false if myOffset = target

             invalidate();
         } 

        try {
            synchronized (Application.getEventLock()) {
                Ui.getUiEngine().suspendPainting(true);
            }

        } catch (final Exception ex) {

        }

    }

    protected void paint(Graphics g){

           //control x,y positions of the bitmaps in the timer task and the paint will just paint where they go

        g.drawBitmap(0,0, 360,
                480, toBmp, 0, 0);
        g.drawBitmap(0, 0, 360,
                480, fromBmp, 0, 0);     
//      invalidate();

        }

    protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent event) {
        if (!this.isFocus())
            return true;
        if (event.getEvent() == TouchEvent.CLICK) {      

    //      invalidate();
        }
        return super.touchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're working with version 5.0 or later of the OS, this page has a simple example:

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Screen_transitions_detailed_overview_806391_11.jsp

From where did you get the code sample posted in your question?  That code does not appear to be close to working.

**Update:**  you can actually animate transitions like this yourself fairly simply.  Assuming you know how to use the Timer class, you basically have a class-level variable that stores the current x-position of your first Bitmap (the variable would have a value of 0 initially).  In each timer tick, you subtract some amount from the x-position (however many pixels you want it to move each tick) and then call `invalidate();`.

In each call to the paint method, then, you just draw the first bitmap using the x-position variable for the call's x parameter, and draw the second bitmap using the x-position variable *plus* the width of the first bitmap.  The resulting effect is to see the first bitmap slide off to the left while the second slides in from the right.

A *caveat* :  Because this is java (which means the timer events are not real-time - they're not guaranteed to occur when you want them to), this animation will be kind of erratic and unsmooth.  The best way to get smooth animation like this is to pre-render your animation cells (where each is a progressive combination of the two bitmaps you're transitioning between), so that in the paint method you're just drawing a single pre-rendered bitmap.

Comment: Thanks for response.I need the flipping effect of pages for all Touch versions tht is from 4.7 OS.How to work with page turning effect for pages.

Comment: How to implement and in which position have to implement the click listener for bitmap for transition of pages and page turn animation?If you implemented it before can you please explain me how to do it?

Comment: Thanks MusiGenesis! I am able to transition the bitmaps with your procedure.Thats great answer.But I need flipping effect for bitmaps from left to right and right to left..How to implement it?

Comment: @Koushik:  to do a good page-flipping effect, you need to be able to resize your Bitmap, so that you can draw it progressively thinner and thinner. This, unfortunately, is a huge problem for you, because only the `EncodedImage` class exposes a resizing method, and `EncodedImage` only works for something like a PNG or a JPEG *file* - not for a `Bitmap` that you're (presumably) creating in-memory. `Bitmap` has a .getArgb() method (I think that's the name) that gives you the raw bitmap data as an int[] array - you'd have to use this to write your own custom resizing method.

Comment: So, to create a Bitmap that is the original height but half the original width, you would average together two columns of pixels from the original for each one column in the new Bitmap; for one that is a third the original width, you would average together three columns from the original for each column in the new one, etc. Make sure you don't use any kind of interpolation for this (linear or otherwise), as all interpolation methods are fundamentally limited in terms of how much an image can be shrunk (usually 50% or 25%) before severe loss of information, which manifests itself as ...

Comment: ... a really crappy-looking shrunken image.

Comment: Once you have this function, your page-flipping effect can be achieved by drawing the top page bitmap progressively thinner and thinner (always left-aligned) over top of the bottom page bitmap (which is normal sized).

Comment: Thank you very much for  the solution MusiGenesis! I am able to do scale bitmaps up and down, but how to shrink the Bitmap so that when user click on it, it should show the flipping animation at the same time it should show the next bitmap. Can we use TouchEvent for bitmaps for click event listener?

Comment: @Koushik: select my answer as the correct answer, won't you please? I'm trying to hit 30K today (click the check mark next to my answer).

Comment: You can handle the clicking in one of two ways: 1) add a Bitmap field to your screen, and render the animation there; add a click/touch handler to the Bitmap field, or 2) don't add any fields at all to your screen, and instead override the screen's `paint` method and draw directly to the `Graphics` parameter in that method; you can add a click/touch handler method to the screen itself, which will let the user basically click anywhere to turn the page (or you can easily determine which side of the screen the click is on and flip accordingly, like the Kindle app does).

Comment: First of all Congrats for crossing 30k today..I am able to resize the bitmap like reducing(scaling) the size of the bitmap on right side for that i am using the following ink http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Resizing-bitmap-without-creating-encoded-image/td-p/269662, but how can I shrink the bitmap so that user can see the flipping page effect..You said dont use the interpolation methods.How can I do it? Plz provide any code..Save me from this issue...