# Make part of the screen generate click events?

Tags: blackberry

In my application I have an ordered sequence of bitmaps where I need to flip them right to left and left to right, based on whether the user clicked on the left or right of the screen after the bitmap loads.

I need to implement the click event on the screen only after the bitmap is painted to the screen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do screen transitions when the user clicks on a bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795539/do-screen-transitions-when-the-user-clicks-on-a-bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very vague question. If you are using a Screen object and simply drawing the bitmaps by overriding the paint() method, you just need to also override the touchEvent() method and handle that. But without any code it's hard to give you specific advice.