# Resizing bitmaps on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I am working with resizing bitmaps in an application by using the BlackBerry Support Forum thread ["Resizing bitmap without creating encoded image"](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Resizing-bitmap-without-creating-encoded-image/td-p/269662). But with the code from that thread, I can reduce the bitmap right-to-left only, from width 360 to 0, how can I resize it left-to-right.

Comment: Rescaling operates on an image in some direction, but the result will be a scaled image - there is no left-to-right or right-to-left consideration in the result.   What is the problem you are running into?

Comment: Hi Micheal When I give the width in the method resizeBitmap(Bitmap image, int width, int height) as 320 , then it is reducing 40 pixels from right end. I want to reduce it from left end..How can I do it.

Comment: I think you mean 'crop' rather than 'resize'    Resize means you keep all parts of the picture while increasing or decreasing the number of pixels used.   'Crop' means you are removing large parts of the picture.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do screen transitions when the user clicks on a bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795539/do-screen-transitions-when-the-user-clicks-on-a-bitmap)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    int oolddWidth;
int oolddHeight;
int ddispplayWidth;
int ddispplayHeight;
EncodedImage eih1 = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("add2.png");
oolddWidth = eih1.getWidth();
oolddHeight = eih1.getHeight();
ddispplayWidth = Display.getWidth()-40;
ddispplayHeight = 80;
    int nnumeerator = net.rim.device.api.math.Fixed32.toFP(oolddWidth);
    int ddenoominator = net.rim.device.api.math.Fixed32.toFP(ddispplayWidth);
    int wwidtthScale = net.rim.device.api.math.Fixed32.div(nnumeerator, ddenoominator);
    nnumeerator = net.rim.device.api.math.Fixed32.toFP(oolddHeight);
    ddenoominator = net.rim.device.api.math.Fixed32.toFP(ddispplayHeight);
    int hheighhtScale = net.rim.device.api.math.Fixed32.div(nnumeerator, ddenoominator);
    EncodedImage newEih1 = eih1.scaleImage32(wwidtthScale, hheighhtScale); 
    final Bitmap header1 = newEih1.getBitmap();
```